# msmpeng.exe writing huge TMP* files to c:\windows\temp

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

We're having the following problem on one of our Windows 10 (version 1903) workstations.

At random intervals, about once every two days, msmpeng.exe starts writing files of up to 15GB to c:\windows\temp, with names like TMP0000002E27D3A3A88E075D32. It keeps adding more files until the drive is full and the system grinds to a halt. Resource monitor shows msmpeng.exe reading equally fast as it is writing.

I've tried to look into this in detail, and found something that might possibly be relevant. The same temp folder contained a small log file called MpCmdRun.log that got updated about 4 minutes before the TMP-issue started. Here's the tail:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MpCmdRun: Command Line: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\platform\4.18.1907.4-0\MpCmdRun.exe" SignaturesUpdateService -ScheduleJob -HttpDownload -RestrictPrivileges
 Start Time: ‎Tue ‎Aug ‎20 ‎2019 13:25:33

MpEnsureProcessMitigationPolicy: hr = 0x1
Run as Network Service
MpCmdRun: End Time: ‎Tue ‎Aug ‎20 ‎2019 13:25:33
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MpCmdRun: Command Line: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\platform\4.18.1907.4-0\MpCmdRun.exe" SignatureUpdate -ScheduleJob -RestrictPrivileges
 Start Time: ‎Tue ‎Aug ‎20 ‎2019 14:25:35

MpEnsureProcessMitigationPolicy: hr = 0x1
Run as Network Service
MpCmdRun: End Time: ‎Tue ‎Aug ‎20 ‎2019 14:25:36
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MpCmdRun: Command Line: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\platform\4.18.1907.4-0\MpCmdRun.exe" SignaturesUpdateService -ScheduleJob -HttpDownload -RestrictPrivileges
 Start Time: ‎Tue ‎Aug ‎20 ‎2019 14:25:37

MpEnsureProcessMitigationPolicy: hr = 0x1
Run as Network Service
MpCmdRun: End Time: ‎Tue ‎Aug ‎20 ‎2019 14:25:37
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With process explorer I saw that msmpeng.exe also had locks on these log files:

- c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows
  Defender\Support\MPDetection-20190729-093413.log
- c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows
  Defender\Support\MPLog-20190705-153212.log

Yet they don't seem to contain any logging around the time of the issue.

Given the appearance of msmpeng.exe and mpcmdrun.exe this is clearly a Windows Defender related issue. I can find some similar symptoms on other forums, yet only related to Windows XP, 7, in very outdated posts.

Would anyone have a clue as to how to debug this?

Comment: Do you have malware that is trying to disable defender?

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Could this be a symptom of that? I'll do a MBAM sweep ...

Comment: @Moab: Nop, pristine clean ...